# How to copy textures in OpenGL es?

Tags: opengl-es

How can i assign 1 texture to another in OpenGL ES?

I have a class called Objects, which has a member called texture. It has a copy constructor to copy all the data. If i pass an object, which already has a texture set up and just assign it,

```
texture = obj.texture
```

It does not work. What can i do to make it work?

actually it is called gameObjects. here is the copy constructor

```
GameObject::GameObject(const GameObject &dummy)
{
orientation = dummy.orientation;
speed = dummy.speed;
deltax = dummy.deltax;
deltay = dummy.deltay;
position = dummy.position;
active =true;
name = dummy.name;
texture = dummy.texture;
rect = dummy.rect;
fixedWidthRatio = dummy.fixedWidthRatio;
fixedHeightRatio = dummy.fixedHeightRatio;

currentWidthRatio = dummy.currentWidthRatio;
currentHeightRatio = dummy.currentHeightRatio;

}
```

Comment: First ill say never have a class named `Objects`, if its really its name, it's quite confusing.

Comment: I guess we'd need to see the copy constructor, then.

Comment: just added it to the post

Comment: texture is a class of your project, not an opengl es structure.